# What is the proper way to upload a file using CUploadedFile

Tags: php, yii

I am following the tutorial http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/ for uploading a file. I have written the following code :

```
$menuitem->attributes = $_POST['MenuItems'];
$menuitem->clientId = Yii::app()->user->clientId;
$menuitem->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($menuitem, 'image');
if($menuitem->save()){
   $menuitem->image->saveAs(
       Yii::app()->getBasePath()."/../../".$menuitem->image->getName()
   );
}
```

But the problem is that if a file with the same name exists on the same directory, the files is neither overwritten or saved with a different name.
What I want is the new image say image.jpg, if a file of the same name exists, to be renamed to : `image_1.jpg`

Is it possible ? Please reply.

Comment: Just add the number in case you need it. That simple. Go ahead, you can make it happen!

Comment: @hakre I meant i need to add the numbering only if the file with the same name exists in that directory. I'm just asking if there is any built in function to handle that. Otherwise I would have to do a file_exists() check and loop through filenames with numbers until a valid filename is reached. If Yii can handle that too then it would have been nice.

Comment: Then check the API documentation of YII what it offers. Have you done that?

Comment: There is no built in functionality like that, you can perhaps extend the CUploadedFile class and write a more complete saveAs method.

Answer (score 1):

i have wrote a behavior for simple uploading file in yii

you can see guide and download file on [github](https://github.com/na3r/NUploadFile)

Answer (score 0):

I alwais rewrite original name with md5() function. Try this code. All images will have a unique name. This will save your model, and then generate a unique name. And save again the model. Is not very clean but works!

```
$menuitem->attributes = $_POST['MenuItems'];
$menuitem->clientId = Yii::app()->user->clientId;
if ($menuitem->save()) {
    $imageName = @$_FILES["MenuItems"]["name"]["image"];
    $uniqueName = (md5($imageName . mktime() . $menuitem->id)) . '.' . (end(explode('.', $imageName)));
    $original = Yii::app()->getBasePath() . "/../../" . $uniqueName;
    $menuitem->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($menuitem, 'immagine');
    $menuitem->image->saveAs($original);
    $menuitem->image = $uniqueName;
    $menuitem->save();
}
```

Comment: explode function for getting extension name is not a good idea, could cause of error if multiple dot available in file name

Answer (score 0):

I've write these code to upload a file and save path in database using bind parameters

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Form'];
$uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'resume');
$path = '/protected/upload/'.time().$uploadedFile;
if($model->validate()){
    $connection=Yii::app()->db;
    $filePath=Yii::app()->basePath .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.$path; // file upload location

    $result = $uploadedFile->saveAs($filePath); //upload file

// an SQL with placeholders 
$hobbies=implode(",",$model->hobbies); // comma deliminated string of hobbies
$dob =date('Y-m-d',strtotime($model->dob)); // convert date 
$status=1; // status of record
$sql='INSERT INTO student (name, dob, email, gender, hobbies, city, resume, message,status, created_date,modified_date) VALUES(:name,:dob,:email,:gender,:hobbies,:city,:resume,:msg,:status,now(),now())'; 

$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);

// replace the placeholder with the actual username value
$command->bindParam(":name",$model->name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(":dob",$dob,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(":email",$model->email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(":gender",$model->gender,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$command->bindParam(":hobbies",$hobbies,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(":city",$model->city,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$command->bindParam(":resume",$path,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(":msg",$model->msg,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(":status",$status,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result=$command->execute(); 

}
```

I hope these is useful for you.